# What is the difference between BertModel vs Bertforsequenceclassification?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a data frame with 2 columns(a column of text data and a target feature), and would like to train the data for classification. . I was curious what is the main difference between these two?

So far, I have been using Bertforsequenceclassification, but I saw that mostly use BertModel for this purpose in Kaggle competition etc

Answer (score 0):

`BertForSequenceClassification` is built on top of `BertModel`. You can't train a classifier using `BertModel` out of the box. The `BertForSequenceClassification` effectively takes the `BertModel` and builds a classification layer on top (plus some additional elements such as adding the right activation and loss function). If you're fluent with python you can see the [source code here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1516).
In short, you either take `BertForSequenceClassification` or you build something similar yourself starting from `BertModel`.